# Lots of CLOSE_WAIT and SYN_RECV Captured From ARBITERS With 'netstat'

Tags: mongodb

I have a cluster with 7 nodes: 1 primary, 3 secondary and 3 arbiters.
I also have several more app servers which communicate with the cluster.
Recently, we've received lots of errors in the mongodb log (prim / secondary) like

> Error in heartbeat request to ARBITER01:<port>

Also, from mongodb logs of the 3 arbiters having the same errors of timeout when trying to connect to other arbiters.
The loads are high in the 3 arbiters due to we captured lots of CLOSE_WAIT (>300) and SYN_RECV (>100) and most of them pointing to the app servers

Questions:

1. What can cause these errors while the app doesn't have anything to do with ARBITERS?

   ```
   ~]# netstat -an | grep <app IP>
   ```

   > tcp 0 1 ::ffff::48098 ::ffff::27757 SYN_SENT
   >   tcp 0 1 ::ffff::44796 ::ffff::27737 SYN_SENT
   >   tcp 0 1 ::ffff::60354 ::ffff::27721 SYN_SENT
   >   tcp 0 1 ::ffff::49100 ::ffff::27719 SYN_SENT
   >   tcp 0 1 ::ffff::52536 ::ffff::27717 SYN_SENT
   >   tcp 0 1 ::ffff:.159:44446 :::27720 SYN_SENT
2. Is there any bug from java driver used with mongodb 3.2.19?

   ```
   rpm -qa | grep mongo
   ```

   > mongodb-org-server-3.2.19-1.el7.x86_64
   >   mongodb-org-shell-3.2.19-1.el7.x86_64
   >   mongodb-org-tools-3.2.19-1.el7.x86_64
   >   mongodb-org-mongos-3.2.19-1.el7.x86_64
   >   mongodb-org-3.2.19-1.el7.x86_64

The reason we have 3 arbiters is because we have 3 regions for the replica set of 7 nodes.
We use VM Centos 7 for all the nodes and the arbiters have 8 CPUs.
Is it true that we can reduce the load if all arbiter members are set to priority 0 and hidden = true as we are in MongoDB version 3.2.12 (arbiter's priority default is 0 for 3.6)?
The issue here is we see too many CLOSE_WAIT and SYN_RECV sockets with several connections from the app servers. They come and go but the numbers are always *high*. It's also caused sometime, the primary/secondaries' logs showing heartbeat timeout to these arbiters.

Comment: I'm finding this question very difficult to read. Could you perhaps a) use more line-breaks and b) use the formatting tools at the top of the edit window to make the question clearer? I'm afraid that I know next to nothing about MongoDB, but a clearly written question will assist you in getting good answers - help us to help you! p.s. welcome to the forum :-)

Comment: How the nodes are split between region? I mean which nodes are in which region? It looks like you don't need three arbiters. Also, you have only 3 regions and why there 4 data nodes(1 primary and 3 secondaries). Please post the `rs.status()` value as well.